# Postgres Function to Try 3 Inserts One By One?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a procedure (I'm extremely new to RDBMS), where given a user's details, and an array of courses, the procedure will try to enroll the user to the course. If it succeeds, the procedure will quit with code 1, else it will try again for the second course in the array, and so on till the third.

Here is what I came up with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  enroll_user_procedure(userID INTEGER, REFID INTEGER[], REFTYPE CHARACTER VARYING, slotNO SMALLINT)  
RETURNS code AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_enrollments(user_id,ref_id,type,slot) VALUES (userID,REFID[1],REFTYPE,slotNO) RETURNING enroll_id INTO enroll_id;
 EXCEPTION
     WHEN SQLSTATE 'COUFL' then
   INSERT INTO user_enrollments(user_id,ref_id,type,slot) VALUES (userID,REFID[2],REFTYPE,slotNO) RETURNING enroll_id INTO enroll_id;
   EXCEPTION
       WHEN SQLSTATE 'COUFL' then
     INSERT INTO user_enrollments(user_id,ref_id,type,slot) VALUES (userID,REFID[3],REFTYPE,slotNO) RETURNING enroll_id INTO enroll_id;
     EXCEPTION
         WHEN SQLSTATE 'COUFL' then
      RETURN QUERY SELECT 0 INTO code;
     END
   END;  
 END; 
    COMMIT;
END;
$$; LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Where COUFL is raised by this trigger function:

```
if enroll_count >= courses_limit then
    UPDATE courses SET status = 0 WHERE course_id = NEW.ref_id; 
    RAISE EXCEPTION USING
        errcode='COUFL',
    message='course_full';
end if;
```

My problem: I'm new with procedures and functions, so I want to know if this is the right way of doing it? Or is there a better way? Also, this function gives an error saying " Language not specified." even though I did. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: and the issue is...? You've told us the requirement, shown us an attempt, but forgotten to explain what problem you'd like help with. Can you clarify?

Comment: Whats the `code` type ? How have you defined it and why are you using it?  How is the Trigger raised and how is it defined(show the trigger code)? Also, it appears the semicolon should come after the language specification and not before

Comment: @KaushikNayak Code is an integer, no I haven't defined it yet. Earlier, I had written it as ``OUT code INTEGER) `` but then I got return query not allowed with out arguments. I'll post the trigger function in a while.